# Timestamp tag empty in XML - Java Marshaller

Tags: java, xml, timestamp, marshalling

I am not very familiar with `Marshaller` but I gave a try in a project and the `XML` was generated fine. But when I apply the `XML validation (with the .xsd file)` it shows an Error saying that `<Timestamp>` is empty. I debugged the application and I see that inside my Bean the `Timestamp` is `not empty` but when the `Marshaller` generates the XML it is really empty. In the other hand, other attributes which uses `XMLGregorianCalendar` are present in the XML. I don't know what is happening.

This is the XML generator function:

```
public void generateXMLReportFile(String fileOutputDirectory,
                                  String xmlOutputFileName,
                                  CRSOECD crsOECD)
    throws JAXBException, FileNotFoundException, IOException
{
    String encoding = "UTF-8";
    // Schema location to write to generated XML file.
    String schemaLocation = "urn:oecd:ties:crs:v1 CrsXML_v1.0.xsd";

    // Generate The Report:
    JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(CRSOECD.class);

    StringWriter xml = new StringWriter();

    Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
    marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
    marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_ENCODING, encoding);
    marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_SCHEMA_LOCATION, schemaLocation);

    marshaller.marshal(crsOECD, xml);

    try (OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(fileOutputDirectory + xmlOutputFileName)) {
        byte[] bytes = xml.toString().getBytes(encoding);
        out.write(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
        log.info("XML generated.");
    }
}
```

If I debug, I see that the element which is empty in the XML is not empty in the Bean `crsOECD`.

Comment: What actual type `crsOECD.timestamp` has in Java class? Perhaps you need a type converter defined in bindings.xjb file.

Answer (score 1):

Guys I just found the answer. The problem was that my element was tagged like this:

`@XmlElement(name = "Timestamp", required = true)
  @XmlSchemaType(name = "dateTime")`

And I was passing only a `Date` with no `Time`.